# Get product name in url rather than id php

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am working on a shopping cart website for a university project and need some help.

The site is currently under production at http://www.cutecupcak.es.

At the moment, each product has a url of something like http://cutecupcak.es/product.php?id=11, but I want it to be something like http://cutecupcak.es/product.php?id=chocolate_cupcake.

This is the code we have been given to make this work.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `CAKE` WHERE `cake_id`=($id)");    
}
```

What do I need to change to get the `cake_name` to show rather than the `cake_id`?

Comment: Your university is promoting the use of `mysql_query`?

Comment: swap cake_id with cake_name, was that so hard?

Comment: we have been told to use mysql_query.. but will look into the newer code...

Comment: and swapping cake_id to cake_name doesnt work! gives error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you want to reference your products by a name instead of id - you should add a new column (I always name it as "slug") with an UNIQUE key. Then, when product is added or edited, based on its name you generates new value for the slug column. For example - from "Chocolate Cake" you will create "chocolate_cake". Then you have to check if the slug is unique - and if not - resolve conflict somehow (e.g. "chocolate_cake_1").

If you have all this set up - just select the appropriate product by unique slug:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `CAKE` WHERE `slug`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");
```

And - obviosuly - use mysqli instead of deprecated mysql functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: What if you want to change the name of the product? Then your old links are invalid.

Comment: You may think about redirects from old addresses feature ;) But indeed - solution with id & name in one URL is the best and can't be argued.

Comment: this fixed the issue, after i added an extra column for a new cake_url thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put the name in the url, which should be quite simple, since you have both the name and the id in your database and you can search by and use both.

**Both name and id**
But I would advise against it. Product names can change a little, and changing it means that the old link wont work anymore.

I would create an url like this:

```
http://cutecupcak.es/product.php?id=11&name=chocolate_cupcake
```

or rather even:

```
http://cutecupcak.es/product/11/chocolate_cupcake
```

These urls can be indexed safely. You retain the numeric id, which you can use to lookup the number. The name is in the url as well, which is good for readability and for SEO (search engine optimization), but the name has no actual meaning. You can safely ignore it, because you got the number. Therefor all previously indexed and linked urls will remain valid after you change the name.

I would choose to use dashes instead of underscores in the product name. I believe `chocolate-cupcake` and `chocolate+cupcake` are both indexed better than `chocolate_cupcake`, but my information on this topic may be a bit stale.

**mysql? Parameters!**
I also would advise you to no longer use `mysql_*`, and start using `PDO` or `mysqli`. Both allow the use of parameterized queries. This allows you to pass an id or name to a query in a safe and transparent method. Safer, cleaner and better performing than using `mysql_real_escape_string` or functions like that. It's especially safer, because once you become accustomed to using parameters, you will start passing all variables as parameters. While you can forget to escape a variable in your current query, you cannot possibly forget to escape a variable, because it doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Second solution is what I use for one of my sites with the help of URL redirection.

Comment: Yeah, me too. In fact, all request go through the same php file, which parses the full url and determines the right page. Though custom made, it is similar to what most frameworks do, amongst which CodeIgnitor and CMSs like WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `CAKE` WHERE `cake_name`=(". mysql_real_escape_string($id). ")");    
}
```

Note: I also added `mysql_real_escape_string`, as not doing that poses a huge SQL injection risk.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider using `mysqli_...` instead of `mysql_...` as it looks like using the `mysql_...` functions is discouraged. (See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think this just changes to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `CAKE` WHERE `cake_name`=($id)");
```

Comment: Good point, I'm trying to keep a small scope because of the apparent skill level going in.

Answer (score 0):

The Following is a blueprint to what you have to do:
1- In your table you should set cake_name field to be unique.
2- Your sql query should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `CAKE` WHERE `cake_name`=($id)");
```

3- Change the links found of your products list to obtain the cake_name value instead of the numeric id.

Comment: This is the exact same query as @raydowe posted 8 minutes before.

Comment: @GolezTrol The post you regarded did not consider setting the cake_name to be unique. It is very important rule to apply such requirement

Comment: I think in a product database, the name should be unique anyway. How would a customer tell the difference otherwise?

Comment: @GolezTrol By default, the entity is defined by its primary key, in this case, it is the numerical id. So in order to make another field to work as an entity identifier you must set it to be unique.

Comment: A field doesn't need to be a primary key to be unique. You can still have a unique name if id is the primary key. You can even have a surrogate key, which is a different key than the id shown to the outside world. This is not uncommon for product numbers. You can make all those individual fields unique.

Comment: I don't say a word differs than you.

Comment: at the moment it is a fake site so all products are unique... but yes i can see this being an issue in a larger commerical site. thanks for feedback :)